# something wrong with rqt_reconfigure

Tags: ros, rqt-reconfigure, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,
I'm trying to get the pointcloud data from point_clooud2, but I just want the pointcloud data with short depth, so I try to use "rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure" to change the depth  parameter, unluckily, I can't find the node "/camera/depth/points" on the rqt_reconfigure_param dashboard, so if there is anyway I can use to reset the depth parameter of the node "/camera/depth/points" ?
To sum up, I want to get the point_cloud data with short depth.
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65097/something-wrong-with-rqt_reconfigure/) by [David_xiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/4573/david_xiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I understand your problem as you "want to change parameter while nodes are running", am I right?

Hopefully so, then does `$ rosrun dynamic_reconfigure dynparam list` return the node you want? If not, that node is not publishing dynamic_reconfigure-able parameters, which is the root cause of the problem you're seeing. Since [rqt_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/rqt_reconfigure) uses `dynamic_reconfigure` API internally, it can't see what `dynamic_reconfigure` can't.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0